# Where is SO's "User feed" link on Android

Tags: support

I want to create a list of my favorite SO users, to read their interesting answers when I have time.
I have been told that since a "favorite users list" feature does not exist on Stack Exchange, I have to subscribe to that user's RSS feed.

I currently access Stack Overflow from my Android device. When checking the user page on my device, I cannot seem to find that RSS feed. Where is it?

Once I have the user feed, how should I use it, how should I create my "favorite Stack Overflow users list"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if the user feeds are linked on the mobile version of the site (doesn't appear to be), but the URL is always of the form:

```
http://the.site.you.want/feeds/user/userid
```

e.g. your own user feed on Meta is: [wil's feed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/179911).

The feeds are [Atom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(standard)) feeds, you can read them with any good [feed reader/aggreagtor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_feed_aggregators).

Comment: Thank you for the info and the links ! I will +1 your answer when I have enough reputation to do so.